# Moda cuando no hay datos

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente df:

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c("AAA","BBB","AAA","BBB","BBB","AAA","BBB","BBB","C"),
  col2=c(200,800,200,NA,NA,30,30,800,NA)
)
```

```
   col1 col2
1  AAA  200
2  BBB  800
3  AAA  200
4  BBB   NA
5  BBB   NA
6  AAA   30
7  BBB   30
8  BBB  800
9    C   NA
```

Quiero calcular la moda agrupada por la col1

```
Moda <- function(x, useNA = "no") {
  xtabla <- table(x, useNA = useNA)             
  names(xtabla[xtabla == max(xtabla)])}

datos2 %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(Moda= Moda(col2))->datos2
```

Pero da error, porque C  no tiene datos.

¿Hay alguna forma de que añada las modas que sí se pueden calcular y esa la deje en blanco?

El resultado seria algo así

```
        col1 col2
1 AAA     200 200  
2 BBB     800 800  
3 AAA     200 200  
4 BBB      NA 800  
5 BBB      NA 800  
6 AAA      30 200  
7 BBB      30 800  
8 BBB     800 800 
9   C      NA  NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos primero dónde estaría el problema:

```
datos2 %>%
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(Moda= Moda(col2))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Moda`.
x `Moda` must return compatible vectors across groups.
ℹ Input `Moda` is `Moda(col2)`.
ℹ Cannot combine NULL and non NULL results.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Además: Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `Moda`.
ℹ ningun argumento finito para max; retornando -Inf
ℹ Input `Moda` is `Moda(col2)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 3: col1 = "C". 
2: In max(xtabla) : ningun argumento finito para max; retornando -Inf
```

De todo lo que se muestra en pantalla, lo más importante es:

```
x `Moda` must return compatible vectors across groups.
ℹ Input `Moda` is `Moda(col2)`.
ℹ Cannot combine NULL and non NULL results.
```

Lo que nos indica que de alguna manera `Moda()` está en algún momento retornando `NULL` y en otros casos valores no `NULL`, y no podrían combinarse. El `NULL` claramente es el resultado de procesar el grupo que solo tiene valores `NA`:

```
Moda(NA)
NULL
Warning message:
In max(xtabla) : ningun argumento finito para max; retornando -Inf
```

Los `warnings` son importantes, pero no son la cusa del problema, el `NULL` si lo es. Es importante aclarar, que para R, el `NULL` es un nivel de indeterminación mayor que el `NA`. Un `NA` significa "no conozco el valor de cierta variable", el `NULL` "no sé siquiera si existe dicha variable"

Para solucionar este problema, lo más sencillo es agregar un salida prematura, cuando, el vector `x` este lleno completamente de valores `NA` y retornar un `NA`. Algo así: `if (all(is.na(x))) return(NA)`, el código final:

```
Moda <- function(x, useNA = "no") {
  if (all(is.na(x))) return(NA)
  xtabla <- table(x, useNA = useNA)             
  names(xtabla[xtabla == max(xtabla)])
}
```

Comment: Impresionante!. Y que bien te queda el gorro!